# Login and list Facebook friends using Social Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, social-framework

Could someone give me some pointers on how to integrate this? my goal is to get list of friends who installed my app (fb app). initially I need to login user to my app first and list friends who have / haven't installed the app.

PS : I don't want to use Facebook SDK. I had nightmares in the past due to facebook did countless time changing the sdk.

===========
UPDATE

I've successfully login and list my facebook friends. But now problem to list my friend who have the app and list picture as well. I tried this :

URL : https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture

which give me `OAuthException : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` problem.

I tried also in [API Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends?fields=id,name,%20installed,picture), it works without mentioned error.

if I try only `me/friends` works perfectly, it will list down all my friends.

Comment: How is it possible? I get only the total number of friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it, apparently you cannot append inside the URL. you need to pass the fields in parameter inside `SLRequest`

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

NSDictionary *param=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,installed",@"fields", nil];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                  URL:requestURL
                                           parameters:param];
```

Answer (score 4):

First import Social, Account, SystemConfiguration framework in your project.
Then use this code on your.m file

```
-(void)facebook
{
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSString *key = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXX";//get your key form creating new app in facebook app section
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];
             //it will always be the last object with single sign on
             self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];


             ACAccountCredential *facebookCredential = [self.facebookAccount credential];
             NSString *accessToken = [facebookCredential oauthToken];
             NSLog(@"Facebook Access Token: %@", accessToken);


             NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);

             [self get];

             [self getFBFriends];

             isFacebookAvailable = 1;
         } else
         {
             //Fail gracefully...
             NSLog(@"error getting permission yupeeeeeee %@",e);
             sleep(10);
             NSLog(@"awake from sleep");
             isFacebookAvailable = 0;

         }
     }];
   }

-(void)get
{

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:nil];
    request.account = self.facebookAccount;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {

            NSDictionary *list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Dictionary contains: %@", list );

            fbID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list objectForKey:@"id"]];
            globalFBID = fbID;

            gender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [list objectForKey:@"gender"]];
            playerGender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gender];
            NSLog(@"Gender : %@", playerGender);


            self.globalmailID   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list objectForKey:@"email"]];
            NSLog(@"global mail ID : %@",globalmailID);

              fbname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list objectForKey:@"name"]];
            NSLog(@"faceboooookkkk name %@",fbname);

            if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
            {
                [self attemptRenewCredentials];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            });
        }
        else
        {
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
            //attempt to revalidate credentials
        }

    }];

    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSString *key = @"451805654875339";
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"friends_videos"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {}];

}



-(void)getFBFriends
{

    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:nil];
    request.account = self.facebookAccount;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {

            NSDictionary *friendslist =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            for (id facebookFriendList in [friendslist objectForKey:@"data"])
            {
                NSDictionary *friendList = (NSDictionary *)facebookFriendList;
                [facebookFriendIDArray addObject:[friendList objectForKey:@"id"]];
            }


            if([friendslist objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
            {
                [self attemptRenewCredentials];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            });
        }
        else
        {
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
            //attempt to revalidate credentials
        }

    }];

    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSString *key = @"451805654875339";
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"friends_videos"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
     ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {}];

}


-(void)accountChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self attemptRenewCredentials];
}

-(void)attemptRenewCredentials
{
    [self.accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)self.facebookAccount completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error){
        if(!error)
        {
            switch (renewResult) {
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed:
                    NSLog(@"Good to go");
                    [self get];
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected:
                    NSLog(@"User declined permission");
                    break;
                case ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed:
                    NSLog(@"non-user-initiated cancel, you may attempt to retry");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
        else{
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from renew credentials%@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: thanks. but getting facebook friends is working but my problem is getting the friends who installed my facebook app.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?fields=id,name,installed

Did you tried this in Url

Comment: OAuthException : An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. problem.

This error is coming due to access token for resolving this you have to get access token

Comment: Check my own answer. cannot append fields inside the graph url. hope someone find this helpful.